# can any one helps me to resolve the rails mongoid-history gem issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For auditing, I am currently using mongoid-history gem. But when trying to create the records after configuring this gem I am getting below error.

```
undefined method `collection_name' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? collectionize
```

Actually earlier there was no such type of error. Recently this error is occurring and the code has been merged to production. Users are getting this error now and I am in a very bad situation. Please, anyone helps me to resolve this issue because I am unable to identify the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Please include the whole backtrace in your question rather than just the error message.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply. I am using 'mongoid', '~> 6.2.0' gem and for auditing using mongoid-history (0.8.1) gem. I followed the same steps in mongoid history gem and implemented functionality.
class HistoryTracker
  include Mongoid::History::Tracker
end

and in models added like below
class Budget < CostPlan
include Mongoid::History::Trackable
track_history   :on => [:embedded_relations]
end
in controller
@budget.modifier_id = current_user.id added.

Comment: mongoid-history (0.8.1) lib/mongoid/history/trackable.rb:157:in `related_scope'
mongoid-history (0.8.1) lib/mongoid/history/trackable.rb:233:in `history_tracker_attributes'
mongoid-history (0.8.1) lib/mongoid/history/trackable.rb:290:in `track_history_for_action'
mongoid-history (0.8.1) lib/mongoid/history/trackable.rb:245:in `track_create'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'

Comment: mongoid (6.2.1) lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
mongoid (6.2.1) lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:117:in `block in prepare_insert'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
mongoid (6.2.1) lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
mongoid (6.2.1) lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:116:in `prepare_insert'
mongoid (6.2.1) lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:23:in `insert'
mongoid (6.2.1) lib/mongoid/persistable/savable.rb:23:in `save'
mongoid (6.2.1) lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:77:in `block (4 levels) in

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the mongoid-history gem than the issue is resolved.

gem 'mongoid-history', '~> 0.8.2', '>= 0.8.2' update your gem with this version problem will resolves.